# Marshalling a char** in C#

Tags: c#, c, string, pinvoke, marshalling

I am interfacing with code that takes a `char**` (that is, a pointer to a string):

```
int DoSomething(Whatever* handle, char** error);
```

Basically, it takes a handle to its state, and if something goes wrong, it returns an error code and optionally an error message (the memory is allocated externally and freed with a second function. That part I've figued out :) ).

I, however, am unsure how to handle in in C#. What I have currently:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static unsafe extern int DoSomething(IntPtr handle, byte** error);

public static unsafe int DoSomething(IntPtr handle, out string error) {
    byte* buff;

    int ret = DoSomething(handle, &buff);

    if(buff != 0) {
        // ???
    } else {
        error = "";
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I've poked around, but I can't figure out how to turn that into a `byte[]`, suitable for feeding to `UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`

Am I on the right track?

EDIT: To make more explicit, the library function **allocates memory**, which must be freed by calling **another library function**. If a solution does not leave me with a pointer I can free, the solution is unacceptable.

Bonus question: As implied above, this library uses UTF-8 for its strings. Do I need to do anything special in my P/Invokes, or just use `string` for normal `const char*` parameters?

Comment: Have you tried `out StringBuilder`?

Comment: I've added an extra edit clarifying the root problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>You should just be able to use a `ref string` and have the runtime default marshaller take care of this conversion for you. You can hint the char width on the parameter with `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` to make sure that you are using 8-bit characters.</strike>

Since you have a special deallocation method to call, you'll need to keep the pointer, like you've already shown in your question's example.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
private static unsafe extern int DoSomething(
    MySafeHandle handle, void** error); // byte** should work, too, I'm just lazy
```

Then you can get a string:

```
var errorMsg = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(new IntPtr(*error));
```

And cleanup:

```
[DllImport("mydll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)] 
private static extern int FreeMyMemory(IntPtr h);

// ...

FreeMyMemory(new IntPtr(error));
```

And now we have the marshalled error, so just return it.

```
return errorMsg;
```

Also note the `MySafeHandle` type, which would inherit from `System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle`. While not strictly needed (you can use IntPtr), it gives you a better handle management when interoping with native code. Read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx.

Comment: How do I handle the the memory? To reiterate, `DoSomething` will allocate memory and store it in `*error`. I need to free that memory...

Comment: You should know how it is allocated: global heap or local?

Comment: It's heap, but allocated by the library. I need to call `FreeMyMemory` in `mydll.dll` to free it. I can't get the address from a `ref string` to do that.

Comment: Also, I _knew_ there must have been something like `SafeHandle`! Thanks!

Comment: Ah, you need to call a special dealloc method - well, the default marshaller won't do it for you, then. You'll need to pass a pointer on the 2nd parameter. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've posted an answer myself, with what I suspect is inefficient code that demonstrates the exact operations that are required.

Comment: Ah, excellent. I wasn't sure that `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` did what I needed (utf-8). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here is code that compiles (<strike>but, not tested yet, working on that next</strike> tested, works 100%) that does what I need. If anyone can do better, that's what I'm after :D

```
public static unsafe int DoSomething(IntPtr handle, out string error) {
    byte* buff;

    int ret = DoSomething(handle, &buff);

    if(buff != null) {
        int i = 0;

        //count the number of bytes in the error message
        while (buff[++i] != 0) ;

        //allocate a managed array to store the data
        byte[] tmp = new byte[i];

        //(Marshal only works with IntPtrs)
        IntPtr errPtr = new IntPtr(buff);

        //copy the unmanaged array over
        Marshal.Copy(buff, tmp, 0, i);

        //get the string from the managed array
        error = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);

        //free the unmanaged array
        //omitted, since it's not important

        //take a shot of whiskey
    } else {
        error = "";
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Edit: fixed the logic in the `while` loop, it had an off by one error.